# How to refresh Android ListView from inside one function

Tags: android, listview, layout, refresh

I have a problem about refreshing the screen after i add a string to my listview. I add the string and then i use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but the screen doesn't refresh until the function is over. I need it to refresh immediately after i add the string to the listview

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
public ArrayList listaConectados;
private TextView estado;
private ListView listaView;
public static int x;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    estado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.estado_TextView);
    listaConectados = new ArrayList<Dispositivos>();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    listaView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaConectados_listView);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
    listaView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
public void searchConnectedDispositives(View view) {
    ArrayList listaParaActualizar = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i;
    int x;
    String ip = getIpAddress();
    String ipVariable = ip.substring(0,10);
    for(i=0;i<255;i++){
        int result=10;
        String ipTemp = ipVariable +String.valueOf(i);
        try {
            result=pingHost(ipTemp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(result==0){
            Dispositivos nuevo = new Dispositivos(ipTemp);
            arrayList.add(ipTemp); 
            adapter.add(ipTemp);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

The function searchConnectedDispositives is called when I touch one button. When this function ends, the Activity is refreshed.

Comment: What is the pingHost(ipTemp) implementation code ?

Comment: are you running `searchConnectedDispositives` in background? you can only modify your UI on the main thread.

Comment: @ShadabAnsari pingHost(ipTemp) return 0 if establish conection (sending ping to iphost) return 0
 http://pastebin.com/rSzr0MDT  here the complete code.

Comment: @gesuwall How I know if the function is running in background? In debug can i know it? 
And How run a function in main thread?
Thanks.

Comment: your code runs on main thread by default unless you start new threads or use something like an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Observing your code leads me to find out that the real cause of your problem is `pingHost()` which has  `proc.waitFor();` and `waitFor()` is a blocking call.
That means you are holding the UI thread (because this is the thread where you are performing your operation). 
And the reason why your `ListView` gets refreshed only in the last and I'm sure it gets updated only in the last iteration of your `for loop` is the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462314/updating-a-chart-from-an-arraylist-over-time/36462766#36462766) and I have posted the answer for the same. You can read it .

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i don't understand where i should put the handler code.

Comment: You have to pingHost() in non-UI thread and after it gets completed you can update your list. For this purpose you can use AsyncTask too. Check this -http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: I do this, but it doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/YPt8Lqwd
I really apreciated your time, very thanks.

Comment: That's not the solution to your problem. Read the doc from the link I provided. May be you can use AsyncTask for your purpose.