# Updating Android View with iteration?

Tags: java, android, loops, recursion

I am a beginner android developer. (started about a week ago)

I was trying to do some sort of stopwatch app, so I have a Textview that gets updated and a couple of buttons to start / stop.

This was my initial idea:

```
//showing only pseudocode of callback method
run() {
  while(true) {
  //do calculations
  //calling setText -> updating the view
  }
}
```

Then, tinkering around I tried this:

```
run() {
  //do calculations
  //calling setText -> updating the view
  handler.postDelayed(this, 0) //calling this same method recursively
}
```

The second method works like a charm.
What I don't understand is why the first way doesn't work. 
I thought it would be more efficient to use a cycle instead of recursion.

As soon as I click start button, the program locks, can't press anything.
It seems it doesn't even enter the cycle because it doesn't update the view even on the first iteration. I even tried to put a Thread.sleep inside it to 'slow it down' (i thought maybe it's too fast for the system or something) but same result.

So the question would be, why do android views don't like iteration?
Please note that the rest of the code is all the same, and by just removing the loop everything works.

Does it have to do with running on the UI thread? but still, why does the recursive way of doing it works?

Answer (score 0):

```
//showing only pseudocode of callback method
run() {
  while(true) {
  //do calculations
  //calling setText -> updating the view
  }
}
```

In above code snippet, you are trying to `setText()` in non-UI thread which will apparently not work at all, since you can touch your views only in UI thread.

In the other approach, you are passing that job to your handler which is modifying your views in UI thread and hence it works.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but they are both running in the UI Thread. I pass the job to the handler even in the first example, just not recursively. the start button function I call, contains handler.postDelayed(runnableThatContainsThatRunMethodIWrote, 0). The handler is in the UI thread. The only thing that I change in the whole code is the internal of the run() method, to be recursive instead of iterative.

Comment: In that case , I have a answer over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36462314/updating-a-chart-from-an-arraylist-over-time/36462766#36462766) .